# How to include ActionBar in a project compiled with Apache Ant

Tags: android, ant, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'd like to know how to add ActionBar in a project compiled with Apache Ant(i must use it). Using android with Apache Ant always generates a class that extends Activity. However with that i don't get ActionBar. Here is what i tried so far:

1. I did a bit of search and i found out that i need to extend AppCompatActivity. I imported android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity but i always get `package android.support.v7.app doest not exist` as an error when compiling.
2. I copied /android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7 into libs folder in my project and then did the following command in root of project(c:\users\pc\desktop\temp):

`android update project --path . --target 3 --library libs\appcompat-v7`

I got the following as output:

```
`Error: c:\users\pc\desktop\temp\libs\appcompat-v7 is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found). It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them please use the --subproject parameter.`
```

What do i need to do in order to include libraries needed to use ActionBar and then be able to compile the project with Apache Ant?

Comment: "i must use it" -- Google has been recommending that people move away from Ant for 2-3 years. Who is telling you that you "must use it"? "Using android with Apache Ant always generates a class that extends Activity" -- Apache Ant does not generate activities in a standard Android project. "However with that i don't get ActionBar" -- you do on Android 3.0+, if you either use an appropriate system theme (the `Theme.Holo` family on Android 3.0+, `Theme.Material` on Android 5.0+) or specify no theme and have a `minSdkVersion` of 11 or higher.

Comment: "I did a bit of search and i found out that i need to extend AppCompatActivity" -- that is an alternative way to get an action bar, particularly if you are trying to support Android 2.x. The `m2repository` material is for use with Gradle (and, by extension, Android Studio). You can try using the `extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/` project, but YMMV.

Comment: I added `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag and added `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` inside string.xml When i compile i get `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light` comes from `appcompat-v7`. You may have difficulty using `appcompat-v7` with Ant.

Comment: I tried to use `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Light">` and other time  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material.Light">` none of them work. I'am getting similar kind of error. I have target set to 25. I then tried to use min-sdk at 25 but also didn't work.

Comment: All I can recommend at this point is that you move off of Ant and onto more current tools.

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion to use Theme.Holo did solve my problem.(Should have started with that one!). Here is what i did:

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

In strings.xml add:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">`

This is enough to get ActionBar. Now here is rest of code to get items on it. menu_main.xml:

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/share_ic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:title="share"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/search_ic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:title="search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/moreoverflow_ic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:title="moreOverflow"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow" />

</menu>
```

and finally MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```